# Qml table and chart using python

Tags: python, qt, qml

Halo guys, how i can make a table and chart using qml and python as backend for read csv file and live chart the values in table, anyone help, i m using qt creator for make a application for my project...
Thank you

Complete Qml and python code

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take your time to follow the [tour] and read [ask], and consider that we normally answer to specific and detailed questions. We don't provide tutorials or solutions to posts like "I don't know how to do xyz, please show me the code". Make some research on the topic and *do* some efforts in trying to achieve what you want, then, if you still have problems, post a question about those problems, including a [mre] based on your attempts.

Comment: So you expect complete qml and python code? Anything else? A beer while you wait?